# What is the right way to use deferred angular promises with or without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Without angular or typescript, I have the following code:

```
let queue = [
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 0 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("a - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); },
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 2500 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("b - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); },
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 5000 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("c - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); }
];

function SerialCall(queue) {
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
    }
}

SerialCall(queue);
```

I want to replicate this in angular8 and typesript inside of a component. 
I tried npm installing jquery and npm i @types/jquery.
I am seeing the following error with the line "d = d":

```
(local var) d: JQuery.Deferred<any, any, any>
Type 'PromiseBase<never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never>' is missing the following properties from type 'Deferred<any, any, any>': notify, notifyWith, reject, rejectWith, and 2 more.ts(2740)
```

What is the correct way to do what I am trying to do? (execute the first function in queue, after it completes, do the second, then the third). Does not have to use jquery if there is an angular only/javascript way that is more elegant, if there is another standard library for this that is well known and works for what I am trying to do, that is an acceptable answer.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. So `queue.map(x => x())` would have the same results. I suspect that you intended the functions in the queue to return promises.

Comment: Yes, and the key is I want to execute each one sequentially (one after the other) and not all at the same time. If there is a better alternative to do this than even promises, I would like to know.

Comment: You don't, using jQuery with Angular is frowned upon for a reason. They don't play nice together. Learn RxJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example can be done with observables using the [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) function.

```js
const queue = [
   defer(() => of(new Date()).pipe(delay(0)),
   defer(() => of(new Date()).pipe(delay(2500)),
   defer(() => of(new Date()).pipe(delay(5000))
];

concat(...queue).subscribe(console.log);
```

The concat functions emits values from observables in the order they are completed.

Observables are the preferred alternative to promises in Angular, and you can do basically everything you previously did with Promises plus much more.

Promises are *pull* based where a value is resolved. Observables are *push* based where values are emitted. The later allows for declarative programming where you describe how the data stream is modified.

Some tutorials on observables:

https://www.javascripttuts.com/introduction-to-angular-2-observables/
https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-rxjs-observables/
https://medium.com/@kevinwkds/angular-observable-81eea33a1aab